# Programmatically selecting an <option> in a <select> element then immediately de-selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm populating a `<select>` element with file names returned by a php script. After uploading a file, I want the `<select>` element to automatically select the newly uploaded file. The values of the `<option>` elements in the `<select>` element are the file names. I'm using jQuery's `.prop()` function to set the selected attribute. The element seems to be selected but it immediately de-selects.

Here is my HTML:

```
<select id="uploadedFilesSelect" name="uploadedFiles" multiple="multiple" onchange="onSelectUploadedFile();"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
if (result['filename']) {
    $('#uploadedFilesSelect > option:contains(' + result['filename'] + ')').prop('selected', 'selected');
}
```

The javascript code is called in the success handler of an XMLHttpRequest call to a PHP script which handles the upload.

Observing what happens when I upload a file, I notice that the  element scrolls to the new file and briefly selects it, but it then de-selects. Also, you'll notice I have another event handler, `onSelectUploadedFile()`, binded to the `onchange` event. This event fires when I manually click on a file but not when it "briefly" gets selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: full success handler

```
function uploadComplete(evt) {
    // Parse the returned json string
    var result = JSON.parse(evt.target.responseText);

    // Refresh the select box
    populateSelectWithFiles();

    clearFileInput();

    // Select the uploaded file in the select element
    if (result['filename']) {
        $('#uploadedFilesSelect > option:contains(' + result['filename'] + ')').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
}
```

The function `populateSelectWithFiles()` calls a php script to add the file names to the `select` element.

The function `clearFileInput()` just clears the file input element by creating a new one and replacing the on the page.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? Are there any other events being fired? Blur events, maybe... can you post the full code of the ajax success?

Comment: @Kurt This is for work and, unfortunately, cannot be shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to trigger the onchange event yourself, .prop() will not trigger this. You can use:

```
$('#uploadedFilesSelect').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This works halfway but I'll take it! It doesn't work fully in it that the option doesn't remain highlighted. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: try $('#uploadedFilesSelect').trigger('focus');

Comment: Closer, it selects but still immediately de-selects. But now, when it selects, it changes to blue and not the gray color. I'm assuming the blue is focus color.